# how to append values to a plsql table

Tags: oracle, plsql, extend

I have to get ID values from 3 different queries (Q1, Q2 and Q3 below) and append them to a plsql table so that I can use it later on using table(). But I am unable to "append" to the table. Can you please let me know how to go about this? I am in Oracle 12G. I dont want to union all the queries as in my production scenario, I need to pull from 15 different queries and dont want to write a huge one. And everytime, I "put" into this plsql table, the earlier data gets wiped and doesnt see to append. Any idea how to achieve this using plsql table ?

```
CREATE OR replace PACKAGE pkg AS
  TYPE customer_id_table_type IS TABLE OF all_customers.customer_id%TYPE;
  PROCEDURE process_customers;
END pkg;
/

CREATE OR replace PACKAGE BODY pkg AS

 PROCEDURE process_customers IS
  customer_id_table customer_id_table_type := customer_id_table_type();
  BEGIN 

  -- Q1
  SELECT customer_id BULK COLLECT
  INTO   customer_id_table
  FROM   old_customers cust
  WHERE  cust.last_update_date BETWEEN SYSDATE - 100 AND    SYSDATE;

  -- Q2
  SELECT customer_id BULK COLLECT
  INTO   customer_id_table
  FROM   new_customers cust
  WHERE  cust.last_update_date BETWEEN SYSDATE - 100 AND    SYSDATE;

  -- Q3
  SELECT customer_id BULK COLLECT
  INTO   customer_id_table
  FROM   archive_customers cust
  WHERE  cust.last_update_date BETWEEN SYSDATE - 100 AND    SYSDATE;

  FOR rec IN
  (
         SELECT customer_info
         FROM   all_customers acc
         WHERE  customer_id IN  (SELECT * FROM TABLE(customer_id_table)))
  LOOP
    dbms_output.put_line('customer info: '|| rec.customer_info);
  END LOOP;
 END process_customers;
END pkg;
/
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So there's no `BULK COLLECT APPEND` or anything, but you can combine multiple nested tables with [`MULTISET UNION`](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/operators006.htm#SQLRF51170). So you could populate multiple nested tables and then combine them. I'm not sure what the performance would be compared to a single `UNION` SQL query, but I expect it would be much better than anything working in a loop.

So you'd do something like this:

```
SELECT customer_id BULK COLLECT
  INTO   customer_id_table_1
  FROM   old_customers cust
  WHERE  cust.last_update_date BETWEEN SYSDATE - 100 AND    SYSDATE;

SELECT customer_id BULK COLLECT
  INTO   customer_id_table_2
  FROM   new_customers cust
  WHERE  cust.last_update_date BETWEEN SYSDATE - 100 AND    SYSDATE;

customer_id_table_1 := customer_id_table_1 MULTISET UNION customer_id_table_2;
```